# How to include ruby code in a Javascript String

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am making a function that on click it will append more date fields. Although the 'form' tag keeps getting outputted by the file and failing.

```
 $('.add-date-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        console.log('btn clicked')

        var appendStr = '<div class="form-group classes-field-one-time date-field">' +
                          '<label>If recurring once: <br />Add Date</label>' +
                          '<%= form.date_field :event_date, :class => 'form-control' %>' +
                          '</div>'


        $('#recurring-dates').append(appendStr)
    })
```

The line "form.date_field" is what is failing. How can I add this to a string?

Comment: Try to use `""` double quotes, and inner is single  quotes

Comment: What is the filename called?

Comment: @7urkm3n I will try that

Comment: @Mark file name is _modal_form.html.erb ... which makes sense its a ruby file but weird that it gets outputted in a js string

Answer (score 0):

ERB (Embedded RuBy), which is what goes in the `<%= %>` brackets, will only be executed when run on the server side, as Ruby is a server-side language. By contrast, what you're doing here is just on the client-side, and so Ruby is not involved at this point.

So in order to execute Ruby code again, you'll have to make a call to the server. And unless you want the page to reload, that call will have to be an asynchronous one. Fortunately, this is a pretty standard practice, and Rails makes it pretty easy! There are tons of good tutorials online outlining how to do this. [Here's one from Codeship](https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/), you can find others by just googling something like "Rails render partial with AJAX".